# Something similar to endorsements?

Tags: ratings, profile

I'm looking for suggestions on the endorsements of skills in LinkedIn. It will be used on a corporate platform where profiles have 1 or more skills.

**Ideas** so far are: "+1" or "like" (with a thumb up). In my opinion is the "+1" not very clear on what it means, and the "like" feels to informal to me.

Also thought about the "star", but we will also be using a "star" in the platform,to mark documents that you like. I'm worried that this will be confusing.

Do you have a suggestion on graphical representation to endorse someonse skill?

Background;
I'm working on a corporate knowledge platform, where profiles exist.
A user can add skills to his profile, chosen from predefined skills or fill in his own.
Other users (colleagues) can endorse your skills.

Comment: If users are endorsing other users, then call it that.

Comment: If by 'graphical representation' you're asking for an icon request / suggestion, then I'm afraid [that's off-topic for this site](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions)

Comment: Totally agree! I'm looking for graphical representation examples of endorsements.

Comment: I feel the way you present endorsements lies in the users experience of a system

Comment: maybe some form of a document icon with a +?

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea behind endorsement is informing, that a person knows about some skill.

*Endorse* is a good word for that, because it incorporates both *confirming* and *adding new* skill. There are, however, other ways how to approach it, I think. You could add little +/- buttons next to each skill, which would work like the up/down arrows here, on StackExchange. It would extend the functionality a bit, because someone could say that a person does not possess a skill. You could also use e.g. 1-5 stars rating for the skills. There are just many ways how to apporach it.

Now, back to graphical representation - I know a thumb up is kinda related to Facebook, which can lead to misunderstanding. In this case, a [+] button seems to be better for that. If you plan also endorsing for new skills, you could actually split these two and use *[Confirm] (that this person knows about something)* and treat *[Add new skill*] separately.

Comment: Thanks Dominik, you gave the right interpretation on my question. I'm looking for graphical representations of endorsements!

Still looking for different graphical representations though.

I feel the + and -, I think some of our clients could appriciate it, but i expect most will be turn down. Feels a bit harsh to -1 skill on a colleague in public right?

Comment: In a meanwhile i found some business web applications using "high five"! To me this feels a bit informal, but maybe easy to use; It feels more exciting and fun to high five a colleague instead of a formal "endorsement".